# compute and get the max for EACH row member

Tags: sql

i am trying to build a query to compute Which org has the highest officers attendance each month in each district?
Terms:
"District" and "loinum" mean the same thing. There are 31 districts in Massachusetts.
"Org" is a local chapter, which is in one of the Districts.
"Officers" are the positions named "WM" through "TY".
the table is

```
loinum month   year  org  wm sw jw  ty
1        8     2011  Ma   0   1  1  1 
1        9     2011  CA   1   1  0  0 
1        8     2011  La   1   0  0  1 
2        7     2011  ME   1   1  1  1
2        6     2011  io   1   0  0  0  
2        9     2011  BO   1   0  0  0 
3        5     2011  Ch   1   1  1  1
3        4     2011  AL   0   0  0  1   
3        4     2011  EG   0   1  1  0
```

how  i can compute and get the max for EACH loinum and EACH month ?

Comment: By "month" you mean, of course, month *and* year, don't you?

Comment: month and loinum .but what i saw at some websites, max function can give the max for one only :(

Comment: EX , max attendance was at Ma for loinum 1, for SEP was CA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a generic solution although for specific DB's there may be better. Create an inline view that gets the max of the values for each loinum, month, and year. Then join it back to the main table.

Note:  If there's a tie for max there will be multiple results for a given loinum, month, and year

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM   table1 t 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT loinum, 
                          month, 
                          year, 
                          Max(wm + sw + jw + ty) oCount 
                   FROM   table1 
                   GROUP  BY loinum, 
                             month, 
                             year) AS MAX 
         ON t.loinum = max.loinum 
            AND t.month = max.month 
            AND t.year = max.year 
            AND ( wm + sw + jw + ty ) = max.oCount
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2dcaf/1)

Results

```
LOINUM  MONTH   YEAR    ORG WM  SW  JW  TY
1           8   2011    Ma  0   1   1   1
1           9   2011    CA  1   1   0   0
2           6   2011    io  1   0   0   0
2           7   2011    ME  1   1   1   1
2           9   2011    BO  1   0   0   0
3           4   2011    EG  0   1   1   0
3           5   2011    Ch  1   1   1   1
```

Comment: but at loinum 1 , org " CA" has less attendance than org "Ma", and show up at the result ?

Comment: You did say each month and each lionum right? Is there an org with a higher attendance for September in the 1st loinum than CA?

Comment: sorry :) , i mean a Separate table for each one .

Comment: for this function, i am getting this error "Error 1054: Unknown column 'max.loinum' in 'on clause'" ?

Comment: well I'm guessing MySQL is your DB from your error. Here's the [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1e11/1) for that. Not sure why you're getting that error though since it worked for me

Comment: @Michael Shokery: If you want separate tables, you'll need separate queries, and Conrad's could be taken as a template. Just use `wm`, `sw`, `jw` or `ty` individually instead of `wm + sw + jw + ty`. @Conrad Frix: Far from being sure but maybe the issue with the unknown column is related to the fact that the subselect is aliased `MAX` and is referenced in the `ON` clause as `max` (I mean, the OP might have its server set up as case-sensitive, if that makes any sense).

Comment: @Andriy M : YES , it is a case sensitive .

Comment: @MichaelShokery: In that case you could try replacing the `MAX` alias with `max`. And it would be really nice if you confirmed whether that actually helped.

Comment: @ Andriy M : i replace max with MAX, it works fine . thank you guyes

Comment: @MichaelShokery yeah sorry about that. Using keywords as table aliases was a bad idea, but I'm glad you worked it.